# Why my VSCode extensions gets inactive whenever I update it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Whenever I update my VSCode, few of my extensions gets inactive automatically. It's get activated if I uninstall the extension and reinstall it. you can find in the screen shot that few are inactive.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very likely those extensions are outdated and are known to have compatibility problems with the current vscode version. Try updating those extension to their latest version.

Also check if you use the latest vscode version.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It happens every time I take update of VScode and install latest version of the extensions. I update all regularly.